# Summary a data frame

Tags: r

I have the following database.
How can I ignore the empty cell and compress into one row ??

```
M = data.frame( Name = c('name','name'), Col1 = c("",1) , Col2 = c(2,""))
M$Col1 <- as.character(M$Col1)
M$Col2 <- as.character(M$Col2)
```

Thank You

Comment: Try `aggregate(.~Name,M,paste,collapse="")`.

Comment: @nicola Thanks but i would like to show "name", "1" , "2" on a row

Comment: @nicola's suggestion gives that output, see the community wiki answer I made for it

Answer (score 1):

As @Nicola already expressed in the comments:

```
M2 <- aggregate(.~Name, M, paste, collapse="")
```

is giving the desired output:

```
> M2
  Name Col1 Col2
1 name    1    2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *aggregate* function to solve your problem.

```
aggregate(M[c("Col1","Col2")], list(M$Name), max, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but is there any way which I can aggregate the character ?

Comment: Use *max* instead of *min* as fun in aggregate. You will get desired output

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `dplyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)
M %>%
    group_by(Name) %>%
    summarise(Col1 = paste0(Col1, collapse = ''),
              Col2 = paste0(Col2, collapse = ''))

##     Name  Col1  Col2
##   (fctr) (chr) (chr)
## 1   name     1     2
```

This works based on the input data without having to convert the columns to characters

```
M = data.frame( Name = c('name','name'), Col1 = c("",1) , Col2 = c(2,""))
```